# Android check permissions

Tags: android, permissions

I have a doubt with new permissions check system because of I'm working with versions android 5.0.3 to 7.X (API-23 and superior) and I don't understand how the check permissions system works.
`manager.openCamera` needs a permission check method to do it works, I know.
First of all i'm working in a Class  (not activity) and in "this" I need to get the context i'm but I can't use get context because it's for api 24... So for which thing I need to replace this "this" and I need to do something else then?
Thank you for all.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // TODO: Consider calling
    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
    //                                          int[] grantResults)
    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
    return;
}
manager.openCamera(cameraId, mStateCallback, backgroundHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a context in the constructor of that class, store it in a member variable and then replace "this" with that member variable (or you could just pass it as an argument to the method where you are running the code).

But to request the permissions you will need and activity, so instead of "just" passing a context you could pass an activity and this way you can use the activity to call both checkSelfPermission and requestPermissions.

Now the problem is: How will you handle the user's response? You should implement the method onRequestPermissionsResult inside that same activity. 
If any activity should be able to handle this, create a BaseActivity class (which inherits from Activity) and override that method inside BaseActivity, every other activity should inherit from this BaseActivity.